# How to get ChildNodes of selected node in DevExpress XtraTreeList?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I am using `DevExpress XtraTreeList`. There are no `checkboxes` used. I want to get all childnode IDs of selected node. Note I already got ID of selected node, I just want to get IDs of child nodes of selected nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [TreeListNodesIterator.DoLocalOperation](http://help.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesOperationsTreeListNodesIterator_DoLocalOperationtopic.aspx) method to iterate via child nodes of specific node and the [TreeListNode.GetValue](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesTreeListNode_GetValuetopic) method to obtain child nodes IDs.

Related links:

- [Using the Nodes Iterator](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1472)
- [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument191)

Comment: Sorry I was unable to to use this thing, i used simple recursive method and got all child nodes :)

Comment: but your effort is also some how good and that was a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ

```
var currentNode = TreeList.FocusedNode;

var childList = currentNode.TreeList.Nodes.Where(p => p.ParentNode == currentNode);
```